# Printing first instance of match in each line of file (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following in an executable .pl file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$file = 'TfbG_peaks.txt';
open(INFO, $file) or die("Could not open file.");

foreach $line (<INFO>) {
        if ($line =~ m/[^_]*(?=_)/){
                #print $line; #this prints lines, which means there are matches
                print $1; #but this prints nothing
        }
}
```

Based on my reading at http://goo.gl/YlEN7 and http://goo.gl/VlwKe, `print $1;` should print the first match in each line, but it doesn't. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `$1` should print the string saved by so-called [capture groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups) (created by the bracketing construct - `( ... )`). For example:

```
if ($line =~ m/([^_]*)(?=_)/){
   print $1; 
   # now this will print something, 
   # unless string begins from an underscore 
   # (which still matches the pattern, as * is read as 'zero or more instances')
   # are you sure you don't need `+` here?
}
```

The pattern in your original code didn't have any capture groups, that's why `$1` was empty (`undef`, to be precise) there. And `(?=...)` didn't count, as these were used to add a look-ahead subexpression.

Answer (score 0):

`$1` prints what the first capture (`(...)`) in the pattern captured.

Maybe you were thinking of

```
print $& if $line =~ /[^_]*(?=_)/;    # BAD
```

or

```
print ${^MATCH} if $line =~ /[^_]*(?=_)/p;   # 5.10+
```

But the following would be simpler (and work before 5.10):

```
print $1 if $line =~ /([^_]*)_/;
```

---

Note: You'll get a performance boost when the pattern doesn't match if you add a leading `^` or `(?:^|_)` (whichever is appropriate).

```
print $1 if $line =~ /^([^_]*)_/;
```